# Is overriding std::to_string for user defined enums the proper way to provide to_string for user defined enums?

Tags: c++, enums, tostring

C++ doesn't have a way to get the string representation of an enum. People get around this by writing custom functions that contain a lot of boilerplate code aka
 `switch` with `case XYZ return "XYZ";`

That of course requires users of the enum to know the name of the custom function.

So I thought I could just add a specialization to `std::to_string` to enable a user to use `to_string` on my enums. Something like this:

```
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#define TEST
class Car
{
public:
    enum class Color
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        White
    };
};
#ifdef TEST
#include <string>
namespace std
{
    std::string to_string (Car::Color c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case Car::Color::Red:
            return "Red";
        case Car::Color::Blue:
            return "Blue";
        case Car::Color::White:
            return "White";
        default:
            {
                assert(0);
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

}
#endif
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::to_string(Car::Color::White) << std::endl;

}
```

Are there any problems with this solution?

Comment: I don't think overloading std functions is allowed, only specializing templates.

Comment: Two things: I would check out the use of `#define str(x) #x` (and the associated `#define glue(a,b) a ## b`) to see if that suits your needs with less boilerplate. Just be sure to wrap it in a function for type safety, and to `#undef` it right after you're done. Second, and less importantly, is you forgot the `break;`s in your switch -- possibly giving a reason not to use one if you aren't feeling super unit-testy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's not "overriding" (which applies to `virtual` functions), and you haven't added a "specialization" (which applies to templates), you've added an overload, which adds a declaration and definition of a new function to namespace `std` and that's forbidden:

> **17.6.4.2.1  Namespace std  [namespace.std]**
>   The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

A better solution would be to overload it in your own namespace, and call `to_string(c)` instead of `std::to_string(c)`. That will find the right function and you don't need to add anything to `std`

Comment: wait, im confused how do u mean "which adds a declaration and definition of a new function to namespace std"... to_string exists in std, right ? do you consider params part of the function so that is why you call it new?

Comment: Yes, it's a new function, isn't it? It wasn't there before. It's not a new _name_ but you are defining a new function. The function `std::to_string(int)` is a different function to `std::to_string(double)` and a different function to `std::to_string(Car::Color)`

Comment: The C++ standard considers parameter types part of the function too, it's not just me: **1.3.17 [defns.signature] signature** <function> name, parameter type list (8.3.5), and enclosing namespace (if any)

Comment: This is one of the good uses of `using std::to_string`.  Stick your `to_string` in the `namespace` of your `enum`, and adl will find it if you use `to_string` without a `::` qualification.  Only use `using etd::to_string` in local scope when the type you are working with is generic...

Comment: I agree that adding to `std::` is not generally a good idea - in this particular case however, I would call for an exception to the rule. Imagine the following code: `template<class T> std::string foo(const T& obj) { return std::to_string(obj); }`. If you don't specialize `std::to_string` to stringify your object and write `abc::to_string` functions in different namespaces, you loose the possibility to write generic code that will call to_string.

Comment: @GaspardPetit, no that's not true, you don't lose the possibility at all: `template<class T> std::string foo(const T& obj) { using std::to_string; return to_string(obj); }` This will find either `std::to_string` or another `to_string` in an associated namespace of `T`. (Did you read Yakk's comment before posting your own?) Adding definitions to namespace `std` is undefined behaviour, and can break your std::lib. Just Say No.

Comment: You are absolutely right!  I did read Yakk's answer but did not realize how it would work until you wrote it explicitly.  The `using` trick in local scope could also account for having `to_string` functions defined in multiple namespaces, so it's perfect and clean.