# C++ convert simple values to string

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream, string-conversion

Right now I use the following piece of code to dummily convert basic types (`int`, `long`, `char[]`, this kind of stuff) to `std::string` for further processing:

```
template<class T>
constexpr std::string stringify(const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}
```

however I don't like the fact that it depends on `std::stringstream`. I tried using `std::to_string` (from C++11's repertoire) however it chokes on `char[]` variables.

Is there a simple way offering an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: Had similar problem, ended up specialising the template in case of literals and char[]... Hope someone knows easier solution.

Comment: @cerkiewny You should post that as an answer.

Comment: What exactly makes you dislike the `std::stringstream` dependency? Because I've done with a [SSTR() macro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5590404/60281) since well before `std::to_string` came about, always liked its ability to daisy-chain multiple `<<`, but can't really post that as an answer because you said "no stringstream"...

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23437778/2567683). Therein the following methods are mentioned : stringstream, to_string, boost::spirit::karma, boost::lexical_cast

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know the only way of doing this is by specialising the template by the parameter type with SFINAE.

You need to include the type_traits.

So instead of your code use something like this:

```
template<class T>
 typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, std::string>::type stringify(const T& t)
  {
    return std::to_string(t);
  }

template<class T>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, std::string>::type  stringify(const T& t)
  {
    return std::string(t);
  }
```

this test works for me:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << stringify(3.0f);
  std::cout << stringify("Asdf");
}
```

Important note: the char arrays passed to this function need to be null terminated!

As noted in the comments by yakk you can get rid of the null termination with:

```
template<size_t N> std::string stringify( char(const& s)[N] ) { 
    if (N && !s[N-1]) return {s, s+N-1};
    else return {s, s+N}; 
}
```

Comment: Nice, but won't work for classes that implement `operator<<`.

Comment: @black My answer will handle that. You just need to tweak the `enable_if` a bit and add in the `ostringstream`.

Comment: Testing whether or not `std::to_string(t)` is well-formed as the SFINAE-condition might be a better check. E.g. `template<class T> auto stringify(T&& t) -> decltype(std::to_string(std::forward<T>(t))) { return std::to_string(std::forward<T>(t)); }`

Comment: @dyp That's a really good solution if you answer with that I'll give you a +1. Otherwise I'm gonna steal that answer into my code.

Comment: `template<size_t N> std::string stringify( char(const& s)[N] ) { if (N && !s[N-1]) return {s, s+N-1}; else return {s, s+N}; }` gets rid of null terminated requirement.

Comment: @Yakk Wow, I didn't know that you could do return constructors without declaring the type!

Comment: @cerkiewny If you have c++14 you can use `enable_if_t<`...`>` instead of `template enable_it<`...`>::type`.

Comment: `constexpr` is meaningless in this answer because `std::string` is not a [literal type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType). And here are more serious flaws. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30276624/2266855) for details.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a simple way offering an elegant solution for this problem?

Since nobody proposed it, consider using [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

This integrates seamlessly with anything that implements std::ostream<< operator and can be extended for custom types.

Comment: I actually thought about it but since he is not happy with STL dependancies with string stream i thought the boost::lexical_cast wont be the way either... but surely it is nice alternative.

Comment: I have found this before: people tend to think that having a dependency to an object, somehow makes the code monolythic/heavy on resources/slow/ugly.

Comment: boost::lexical_cast, at least in my experience, was so slow as to make it unusable.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using `enable_if_t` and if you're going to take in any single character variables you specialize those:

```
template<typename T>
enable_if_t<is_arithmetic<T>::value, string> stringify(T t){
    return to_string(t);
}

template<typename T>
enable_if_t<!is_arithmetic<T>::value, string> stringify(T t){
    return static_cast<ostringstream&>(ostringstream() << t).str();
}

template<>
string stringify<char>(char t){
    return string(1, t);
}
```

Here I'm just specializing `char`. If you need to specialize `wchar`, `char16`, or `char32` you'll need to do that as well.

Anyway for non-arithmetic types these overloads will default to using `ostringstream` which is good cause if you've overloaded the extraction operator for one of your classes this will handle it.

For arithmetic types this will use `to_string`, with the exception of `char` and anything else you overload, and those can directly create a `string`.

**Edit:**

[Dyp suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189926/metaprograming-failure-of-function-definition-defines-a-separate-function?lq=1) using whether `to_string` accepts an argument of `T::type` as my `enable_if_t` condition.

The simplest solution is only available to you if you have access to `is_detected` in `#include <experimental/type_traits>`. If you do just define:

```
template<typename T>
using to_string_t = decltype(to_string(declval<T>()));
```

Then you can set your code up as:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(to_string(T{})) stringify(T t){
    return to_string(t);
}

template<typename T>
enable_if_t<!experimental::is_detected<to_string_t, T>::value, string> (T t){
    return static_cast<ostringstream&>(ostringstream() << t).str();
}

template<>
string stringify<char>(char t){
    return string(1, t);
}
```

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189926/metaprograming-failure-of-function-definition-defines-a-separate-function) to figure out how to use `to_string` as my condition. If you don't have access to `is_detected` I'd highly recommend reading through some of the answers cause they are phenomenal: [Metaprograming: Failure of Function Definition Defines a Separate Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189926/metaprograming-failure-of-function-definition-defines-a-separate-function#comment48788377_30197624)

Comment: Feel free to "steal". No need to add yet another answer based on SFINAE.

Comment: @dyp This seems like a good idea but when I go to implement it, I cannot figure out how to code the diametric opposite. How can I say: "Return string if `to_string<T>` is not defined?"

Comment: You can either turn the trailing-return-type into a trait class, or add a dummy parameter for ordering of overloads. The latter: `template<typename T> string stringify(T&& t) { return stringify(forward<T>(t), 0); } template<typename T> auto stringify(T&& t, int) -> decltype(to_string(forward<T>(t))); template<typename T> string stringify(T&& t, ...);` A more advanced way using inheritance can be found [in this blog post](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/overload-ranking/).

Comment: @dyp Seems like there's got to be an easier way to accomplish this. I added a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30189926/2642059) which you may want to weigh in on.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to overload for the types you want:

```
using std::to_string;

template<size_t Size>
std::string to_string(const char (&arr)[Size])
{
    return std::string(arr, Size - 1);
}
```

since `to_string` isn't a template you can't specialize it, but fortunately this is easier.

The code assumes the array is null terminated, but is still safe if it is not.

You may also want to put the `using` line inside the functions that call `to_string` if you have strong feelings about where `using` belongs.

This also has the benefit that if you pass it a non-null-terminated string somehow, it does not have UB as the one argument `std::string` constructor does.

Comment: Whether or not you want `Size - 1` depends on whether or not it is NUL terminated. So, your code can check for that.

Comment: I was going to do that (ie, pick depending on `arr[Size-1]`), but then if the string contains nulls, one of which happens to be at the end, it will chop off the last one and possibly cause problems.

Comment: I'm confused. If I wanted to store a single binary byte containing `'\0'`, your code will not store it anyway. If I wanted to store a single binary byte containing `'\a'`, your code will not store that either.

Comment: This solution is not perfect. See my answer for some details.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, the most elegant solution is:

```cpp
#include <string>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value, std::string>::type
stringify(T&& value) {
    return std::string(std::forward<T>(value)); // take advantage of perfect forwarding
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value, std::string>::type
stringify(T&& value) {
    using std::to_string; // take advantage of ADL (argument-dependent lookup)
    return to_string(std::forward<T>(value)); // take advantage of perfect forwarding
}
```

Here, if we can construct `std::string` using `T` (we check it with help of `std::is_constructible<std::string, T>`), then we do it, otherwise we use `to_string`.

Of course, in C++14 you can replace `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` with much shorter `std::enable_if_t<...>`. An example is in the shorter version of the code, right below.

**The following is a shorter version**, but it's a bit less efficient, because it needs one extra move of `std::string` (but if we do just a copy instead, it's even less efficient):

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string stringify(std::string s) { // use implicit conversion to std::string
    return std::move(s); // take advantage of move semantics
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value, std::string>
stringify(T&& value) {
    using std::to_string; // take advantage of ADL (argument-dependent lookup)
    return to_string(std::forward<T>(value)); // take advantage of perfect forwarding
}
```

This version uses implicit conversion to `std::string` then possible, and uses `to_string` otherwise. Notice the usage of `std::move` to take advantage of C++11 [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics).

**Here is why my solution is better than the currently most voted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167455/2266855) by @cerkiewny:**

- It have much wider applicability, because, thanks to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), it is also
  defined for any type for which conversion using function `to_string`
  is defined (not only `std::` version of it), see the example usage below.
  Whereas the solution by @cerkiewny only works for the fundamental
  types and for the types from which std::string is constructible.

  Of course, in his case it is possible to add extra overloads of
  `stringify` for other types, but it is a much less solid solution if
  compared to adding new ADL versions of `to_string`. And chances are
  height, that ADL-compatible `to_string` is already defined in a third party library for a
  type we want to use. In this case, with my code you don't need to write any additional code at all to make `stringify` work.
- It is more efficient,
  because it takes advantage of C++11 [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582313/2266855) (by using universal references (`T&&`) and `std::forward`).

**Example usage:**

```cpp
#include <string>

namespace Geom {
    class Point {
    public:
        Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

        // This function is ADL-compatible and not only 'stringify' can benefit from it.
        friend std::string to_string(const Point& p) {
            return '(' + std::to_string(p.x) + ", " + std::to_string(p.y) + ')';
        }
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    };
}

#include <iostream>
#include "stringify.h" // inclusion of the code located at the top of this answer

int main() {
    double d = 1.2;
    std::cout << stringify(d) << std::endl; // outputs "1.200000"

    char s[] = "Hello, World!";
    std::cout << stringify(s) << std::endl; // outputs "Hello, World!"

    Geom::Point p(1, 2);
    std::cout << stringify(p) << std::endl; // outputs "(1, 2)"
}
```

### Alternative, but not recommended approach

I also considered just overloading `to_string`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value, std::string>::type
to_string(T&& value) {
    return std::string(std::forward<T>(value)); // take advantage of perfect forwarding
}
```

And a shorter version using implicit conversion to `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string to_string(std::string s) { // use implicit conversion to std::string
    return std::move(s); // take advantage of move semantics
}
```

But these have serious limitations: we need to remember to write `to_string` instead of `std::to_string` everywhere where we want to use it; also it is incompatible with the most common [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) usage pattern:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string a = std::to_string("Hello World!"); // error

    using std::to_string; // ADL
    std::string b = to_string("Hello World!"); // error
}
```

And it's most probable, there are other problems connected with this approach.

Comment: I like the usage of the is_constructible, I wasn't aware of its existence.

Comment: With clang, you get better error messages with `std::enable_if` than with `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: It may not be obvious to many why ADL is important here, something along the lines of but obviously not the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136497/is-overriding-stdto-string-for-user-defined-enums-proper-way-to-privide-to-str#comment24801066_17136607) added to your answer would be an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Although the the question is not of a *gimme the code* kind, since I already have a solution implemented I thought of sharing it:

```
template <class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(std::string const &head, Tail const &... tail)
    -> std::string;

template <class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(char const *head, Tail const &... tail) -> std::string;

template <class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(char *head, Tail const &... tail) -> std::string;

template <class Head, class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(Head const &head, Tail const &... tail) -> std::string;

inline auto buildString() -> std::string { return {}; }

template <class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(std::string const &head, Tail const &... tail)
    -> std::string {
  return head + buildString(tail...);
}
template <class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(char const *head, Tail const &... tail) -> std::string {
  return std::string{head} + buildString(tail...);
}
template <class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(char *head, Tail const &... tail) -> std::string {
  return std::string{head} + buildString(tail...);
}
template <class Head, class... Tail>
inline auto buildString(Head const &head, Tail const &... tail) -> std::string {
  return std::to_string(head) + buildString(tail...);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto gimmeTheString(std::string const &str) -> void {
  cout << str << endl;
}

int main() {

  std::string cpp_string{"This c++ string"};
  char const c_string[] = "this c string";

  gimmeTheString(buildString("I have some strings: ", cpp_string, " and ",
                             c_string, " and some number ", 24));
  return 0;
}
```