# How Can I Use result_of Instead of decltype?

Tags: c++, type-traits, overloading, decltype, result-of

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167800/2642059) I create a type trait:

```
template<typename T>
using to_string_t = decltype(to_string(declval<T>()));
```

This works just fine but I originally set out to use `result_of` and now it's irking me that I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm trying to replace the line above with something like this:

```
template<typename T>
using to_string_t = result_of<to_string(T)>;
```

But I get a compiler error along the lines of:

> error C2275: 'T': illegal use of this type as an expression
>   note: see declaration of 'T'
>   error C2974: 'std::result_of': invalid template argument for '_Fty', type expected

I've tried several other inputs to `result_of` without success, can anyone help me understand what arguments `result_of` is expecting here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's patch it up. `std::result_of` expects only types, its result should be retrieve from its `type` inner typedef, and you need `typename` to access said typedef because it depends on a template parameter.

```
template<typename T>
using to_string_t = typename std::result_of<decltype(std::to_string)(T)>::type;
                    ^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^
```

Or in C++14, you can drop `::type` and `typename` :

```
template<typename T>
using to_string_t = std::result_of_t<decltype(std::to_string)(T)>;
                                  ^^
```

Fine ?

```
main.cpp:5:68: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

Right, `std::to_string` is overloaded, so we need to disambiguate it by casting it to one of its overloads.

```
template<typename T>
using to_string_t = typename std::result_of<decltype(static_cast<
```

Hold on. We need its return type to express the destination type of the cast. We're back to our starting point.

`std::result_of` can't deal with overloaded functions, because the function has no definite type until the overload is resolved. `decltype` is the only solution here, because it *does* apply overload resolution.

If you're wondering how `std::result_of` can be useful, given the above limitation : it's used for overloaded functors, i.e. classes that overload the `()` operator several times. As the type of the class is known, and does not depend on the call arguments, `std::result_of` works.

... But shouldn't `std::to_string` always return a `std::string` ??

Comment: `decltype(decltype(std::to_string(declval<T>())(declval<T>())` :)

Comment: @bolov Missing closing parentheses, but even then you're calling `std::string` as a function. Also, this hardly avoids `decltype`/`declval` :p

Comment: sry: here it is: `std::result_of_t<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>())(std::declval<T>()))>` (now tested, sry about that). But yeah it uses decltype to get the result of `to_string` in order to create a type used in result_of to get... the result of `to_string`. But... it uses `result_of` :))

Comment: @bolov Can't really argue with that... :p

Comment: @bolov So effectively the only way to allow `result_of` to deal with the overload is to use `decltype` in the template parameter, meaning we should just use `decltype` anyway?

Comment: @Quentin "Shouldn't `std::to_string` always return a `std::string`?" No. If I pass it an invalid argument it won't, say you pass a `string` to `to_string`. That makes a bit more sense in the context of the original question.

Comment: @JonathanMee The only way to retrieve the function's type that `result_of` needs is to resolve the overload. Either we do that manually by casting it (but then we're providing the information we're searching for), or we use `decltype` to do the job inside its non-evaluated context. Which is to say, we're back to square 1.