# error: `type` in `class std::result_of` does not name a type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20, result-of

Example below fails with all compilers I've tried: gcc-8.2, clang-8.0 (both options `--std=c++17` and `std=c++2a` were tried) and zapcc-2017.08.

From my point of view the code sample is valid and should be compiled. Or, at least, there should be a more comprehensive error. It does look like a bug in the std library, not covering this particular case for `result_of`. Am I wrong?

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
struct bar {
    int a;
    long b;
};

template<auto M>
struct foo {
    static auto q(bar & b) {
        return b.*M;
    }
};

template<auto M>
auto qoo(bar & b) {
    return b.*M;
}


// error: 'type' in 'class std::result_of<int(bar&)>' does not name a type
using f = typename result_of<decltype(foo<&bar::a>::q)>::type;
// error: 'type' in 'class std::result_of<int(bar&)>' does not name a type
using q= typename result_of<decltype(qoo<&bar::a>)>::type;
```

Comment: Do any of the quirks listed under the cppreference doc for `result_of` answer your question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're in C++11 mode, which makes it fail for completely different reasons. Put it in C++17 mode and you get the same output the OP showed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ooops [yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea5f765acd36560c).

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - none of five listed there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
using f = typename std::result_of<decltype(&foo<&bar::a>::q)(bar&)>::type;

using q= typename std::result_of<decltype(&qoo<&bar::a>)(bar&)>::type;
```

As better explained by T.C., the `type` in `std::result_of` is the type returned from a type of a callable when called with some argument types.

If you write

```
std::result_of<decltype(foo<&bar::a>::q)>
```

you pass to `std::result_of` only the type of the callable (almost: you also needs a `&` before `foo`); you also have to pass the type of the arguments (only one argument, in this case: a `bar` reference), so

```
std::result_of<decltype(&foo<&bar::a>::q)(bar&)>
```

Answer (score 4):

`result_of_t<F(Args...)>` means "the result of calling/invoking `F` with `Args...`".

`result_of_t<int(bar&)>` means "the result of calling `int` with `bar&`". Which doesn't exist because you can't call an `int` with, well, anything.

`result_of` is *not* "extract the return type from a function type".

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there really isn't anything that `result_of` can do which `decltype` cannot (or [`result_of_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) which would help simplify your code): [How Can I Use result_of Instead of decltype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30595146/2642059)

That holds true in this case as well, where `decltype` and [`declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) will give you a simpler result than `result_of`:

```
using f = decltype(foo<&bar::a>::q(declval<bar&>()));
using q = decltype(qoo<&bar::a>(declval<bar&>()));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c9ca2a52f38b498)

Comment: `result_of` is necessary if you want to support the full range of invocable objects.

Comment: @T.C. I can't think of an example that I couldn't use some combination of `declval` and `decltype` to achieve, but I'd like to understand. Should I ask another question, or is there a simple example you could give in a comment?

Comment: The full range of invocable objects includes pointers to members.

Comment: @T.C. Can't I call a pointer to a member using `declval`? For example: https://ideone.com/25wpKD

Comment: Sure. Now try to write one that works for *both* pointers to members *and* function objects.